# MySQL query not working - can't figure out why

Tags: mysql, join

I have this query that I'm pretty sure it set up correctly, but it keeps returning no results, when I know there is 1 row that should be returned.

```
SELECT
    `t1`.id,
    `t1`.length,
    `t2`.last,
    `t2`.first,
    `t4`.name,
    `t5`.text
FROM `res` AS `t1`
INNER JOIN `pt` AS `t2`
     ON `t1`.ptid=`t2`.pt
INNER JOIN `docs` AS `t3`
     ON `t1`.doc=`t3`.did
LEFT JOIN `user` AS `t4`
     ON `t3`.user=`t4`.id
INNER JOIN `desc` AS `t5`
     ON `t1`.desc=`t5`.id

ORDER BY
     `t1`.date ASC
```

Again, not getting an error - just getting no results.

Thanks

Comment: Just guessing here since there's so little to go on:  Since there's no `WHERE` clause it's likely one of your joins is incorrect.

Comment: maybe this is not apparent from the query, but i need to get the id of the row of t3 and then use that to get a name value for t4. is "INNER JOIN" now the correct way to do that?

Comment: In that case you're joining `t3`.user = `t4`.id are you sure that's correct?

Answer (score 1):

`desc` is a reserved word. You need to put backticks around it.

```
JOIN `desc` as `t5` ON `t1`.desc=`t5`.id
```

should be

```
JOIN `desc` as `t5` ON `t1`.`desc`=`t5`.id
```